# How do I keep the same class instance in unit test?

Tags: python

I'm writing some unit tests for my class and I noticed that the class resets with each test.

```
import unittest
from module import ClassA

class TestA(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.a = ClassA()

    def firstTest(self):
        # Test method and assign instance variables to self.a

    def secondTest(self):
        # Test method with assumption that self.a still have those variables
        # Fails because instance variables are reset
```

Does `unittest` runs `setUp()` for each individual test? If that's the case, how can I update and use the same class instance for all tests?

Comment: Unit tests are supposed to be independent. If `secondTest` depends on `firstTest` running first, then those aren't two tests. That's one big test that should either be put into one method, or changed to remove the dependency.

Comment: Yes, I also agree with @user2357112. Unit test should not be dependent. If the tests are dependent than those are the integration, functional or end to end test cases.

Comment: sometimes individual setUp's are required, like, say for, SQL or for reading really really large documents,
try  setUpClass()¶ (needs to be decorated with @classmethod, see https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUpClass)

Comment: I see. I was thinking that unit test means I just test the functionality of each function or method. So it's better to write each test independently with its own instance variables and only test those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A unit test doesn't necessarily test a single function or method; you can have *multiple* unit tests that test different *aspects* of the same function. For example, a function like

```
def some_func(x):
    if x % 2 == 0:
        return "even"
    else:
        return "odd"
```

should have at least two tests: one that checks that it returns `"even"` for an even value, and another that checks that it returns `"odd"` for an odd value. A third test might check that it raises an appropriate exception if `%` isn't supported by its argument.

A *fixture* is an environment in which a test can be run, represented by a `TestCase`. Each test defined in a `TestCase` uses the same fixture, created fresh before running each test.

Now, in your case, if `secondTest` really does depend on the result of `firstTest`, then that means `secondTest` relies on a separate *fixture* than `firstTest`. That calls for a separate `TestCase` that ensures the appropriate conditions are created for `secondTest` to run correctly.

For example,

```
# Tests that simply require an instance of ClassA
class TestA(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.a = ClassA()

    def firstTest(self):
        # Test method and assign instance variables to self.a


# Tests that require a particular configuration of an instance of ClassA
class TestB(unites.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.a = ClassA()
        self.a.x = 6  # For example

    def secondTest(self):
        # Test something that requires self.a.x be set to 6 first
```

A good test runner would not execute each test sequentially; it would randomize their order (without respect to their grouping within test fixtures) so that no one test can rely on being executed before or after another test.

Comment: Thank you for elaborating on the concept of fixture. I approached testing thinking I can write a class to test another class. Your answer showed me what I need to do.

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to the world of testing !, It'll take a while to get used to, but as far as I can say, It has saved me a couple of times,

couple of issues here, (final answer in the bottom)

1. Test methods need to be prefixed with "test_" by default, this can be changed, (see details of that [here](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestLoader.testMethodPrefix))
2. to answer your question, use the prefix "setUpClass",

here's an example !,

```
class TestA(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.a = OrderedDict()
        print("function 'setUp' was called !")

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.b = OrderedDict()
        print("function 'setUpClass' was called !")

    def test_firstTest(self):
        # Test method and assign instance variables to self.a
        self.assertEqual(1, 1)

    def test_secondTest(self):
        # Test method with assumption that self.a still have those variables
        # Fails because instance variables are reset
        self.assertEqual(1, 1)
```

Comment: That's not going to do anything to preserve instance variables from `test_firstTest` to `test_secondTest`, or even to guarantee that `test_firstTest` actually runs first, or runs at all.